# Sorting points in 3D

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, 3d

If I have a set of points in 3D, and a camera plane, how would I sort them based on distance to that plane? I need pesudo code at least. I want to construct a plane from a camera then sort the points.

Comment: What is your exact problem? Why don't just calculate distances from each point to plain and sort points according to distances?

Comment: my problem is getting the plane and using it to compare distances then sort the points. I'm beginner in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CompareDistance
{
    public float DistanceToCameraPlane(Vector3 pointInSpace)
    {
        var cameraPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
        var cameraForward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
        var deltaToCamera = pointInSpace - cameraPosition;
        var projection = Vector3.Project(deltaToCamera, cameraForward);
        return projection.magnitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: then how would I sort each point, I'm beginner in c# using that class? can you please explain what did you do in picture?

Comment: Use the Array.Sort, for example.

Comment: I mean sorting it by the projection.magnitude ? how would I use your class for sorting ?

Comment: Your task consists of two parts: (1) getting the distance to the camera plane and (2) sorting all the distances. The code above describes how you can complete the first task. After you got all the distances by calling this method on each point you want distance to, you can put them into an array and sort, for example.

Comment: Should I make forward.y = 0?  Can you please make a draw of the math above ? I really want to understand it. Thanks alot!

Comment: @golergka Wouldn't something like this work? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/729ad30040a652d2790d

Comment: @GrawCube that looks like the best way to solve it! However, using delegates and lambdas is something that I try to avoid when explaining stuff to people new to C#, it can create too much confusion.

Comment: @golergka Yeah okay I can understand that. Simpler approach: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f4771b901d3ca2ae2b97

Comment: @golergka can you please draw a picture of the math ?